# Issues with relationships using pocos in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an application where I use POCO classes and I'm getting an error when I try to set a relationship between a new object and a persisted object.

I have these classes: `SecurityUser` and `SecurityGroup`. `SecurityUser` has a property `Group_ID` where I can set the ID for the user group and a property `SecurityGroup` where I can set the object itself. When I try to set a new `SecurityGroup` for this property I get the "null reference" exception on the POCO class. Here's an example of my code:

```
using (SecurityEntities context = new SexurityEntities(connectionString))
{
    SecurityUser user = context.SecurityUsers.SingleOrDefault(cond => cond.User_ID == 1);
    SecurityGroup group = new SecurityGroup();
    user.SecurityGroup = group;

    context.SecurityGroups.AddObject(group);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I do this without using the entity framework without the POCO classes, everything goes well, but with POCOs it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one of those ugly relationship fixup problems which are causing trouble with EF 4 POCOs every now and then.

If you take a look at the classes created by the POCO generator you'll see a region called "*Association Fixup*" containing some methods like `FixupSecurityGroup` or similar called from property setters of your POCOs. I could reproduce your problem but even after debugging I couldn't find exactly the point where it goes wrong in these fixup methods. So, I cannot explain why your code doesn't work.

But I found two solutions which work:

1) Don't create the group with `new` but use the `CreateObject` method:

```
SecurityUser user = context.SecurityUsers
    .SingleOrDefault(cond => cond.User_ID == 1);

SecurityGroup group = context.SecurityGroups.CreateObject();
user.SecurityGroup = group;

context.SaveChanges();
```

(I've removed `AddObject`. It's not necessary because EF recognizes that the group is new and creates an INSERT statement, but removing `AddObject` alone doesn't fix the problem.)

Your POCO properties are `virtual` and EF will create a dynamic proxy for the `SecurityUser` when you load it from the DB. Apparently for some reason a dynamic proxy also for the `SecurityGroup` you create is required, otherwise we get your null reference exception. `CreateObject` will create this proxy.

2) Alternatively you can turn off proxy creation:

```
context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

SecurityUser user = context.SecurityUsers
    .SingleOrDefault(cond => cond.User_ID == 1);

SecurityGroup group = new SecurityGroup();
user.SecurityGroup = group;

context.SaveChanges();
```

Now, `user` is no dynamic proxy and the code also works when you create the group with an ordinary `new` operator.

Comment: The first solution didn't work for me. In fact, I had already tried that. But the second solution, setting ProxyCreationEnabled = false, worked fine. It helped me a lot!! Thanks for that!! :D